# snzip via apt-get?

Tags: software-installation, compression

The `snzip` is a data compressor, based on the Google **Snappy** library. I've found and installed the library itself via `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev
```

but it doesn't include the command tool (which AFAIK is called `snzip`).

Is it any way to download the already built `snzip` via `apt-get`?

Comment: Already built, where?

Comment: The same place from where I `apt-get install` other compressors, like `lbzip2`, `pxz` etc.